# Acces hidden GRUB2 Boot Menu in boot proccess

Tags: grub2, bootloader, 23.04

I want to hide GRUB2 boot menu in Ubuntu 23.04, but it can open from booting proccess as I want. I try to add `GRUB_TIMEOUT = -1`, but it can't hidden and still showing. My `/etc/default/grub` file as it :

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

If I set it `GRUB_TIMEOUT = 0`, I can't open GRUB2 menu but it hidden as well. I try to hold Shift or Esc button but it can't GRUB2 menu. I want to make my Ubuntu like Fedora, it can hide GRUB2 boot menu but it can acces by holding Shift button. What should I do? Thanks for your help

Comment: Do not use 0 as then you never can get to grub menu. I like to use 3 so menu only appears just long enough for me to press a key to change boot.  If install is UEFI, then you press escape key not shift key which was for old BIOS installs. Are you dual booting? Grub wants to show menu if dual booting.

Comment: @oldfred, I'm only single boot Ubuntu 23.04 in my computer. I think I can use 0 for full hide GRUB2 menu, but I want it can accesible to open with a key for open it. I can get it in Fedora, but not in Ubuntu

Comment: Do not know how your Fedora does that. But with Ubuntu and 0 time, you never get grub menu. And if then you need recovery boot, you cannot and then have to use a live installer and chroot into system to make even minor repairs.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. I bit familiar with chrooting for repairing system. Thanks for your explanations